# Malicious request intercepted by spring

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I checked the logs from one of my spring app and found out some strange error messages :

```
UT005023: Exception handling request to /nice%20ports%2C/Tri%6Eity.txt%2ebak
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "%2e"
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:140) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104) [undertow-servlet-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:336) [undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-1.4.22.Final.jar!/:1.4.22.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

I understand that spring received a request that seems malicious, and choose to ignore it.
Since there is no link to '/nice%20ports%2C/Tri%6Eity.txt%2ebak' in my app, is someone trying to do something malicious with my website ? What's the mean of this url ? What was it supposed to do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's most likley a request sent by nmap (and a joke "nice ports trinity" referencing Matrix) which can be used for port- or security-scanning

it is supposed to check how your apps 404 not found page handles special characters

you can read about how this came to be here:
http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2006/q2/207

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there something to fear about it ?

Comment: If it wasn't you our maybe a department of your company running the scan - all that it tells you is, that someone tried to find an open port or a security problem on your system - this is not uncommon for apps on the internet, a lot of people or automates services scan web-apps for possible breaches regularly. Just keep your stuff up to date and stay aware :)